# Why don't show variable in function on label?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code in JavaScript why doesn't it work? I have a text box, a list item, and a button; when I click on the button it should run the function `cal()`.
`cal()` is calculator that calculate and return value like s1, k1,...

Now I have show this value in the label but the code doesn't run!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="checkValue();" />
    <input type="button" value="محاسبه" name="button3" onclick="cal();"/>
    <label id="l1"></label>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
    <script>

      function checkValue() {
        var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var j;
        if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {
          j = 5;
          y.options.length = 4;
          for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
          }
        }
        if (t_value > 25000000 & t_value <= 50000000) {
          j = 8;
          y.options.length = 3;
          for (var i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
          }
        }
      }
      function cal() {
        var mv1 = 0, mq1 = 0, k1 = 0, p1 = 0, s = 0, x = 0, x2 = 0, p2 =                     0, mv2 = 0, y = 0;
        var x1 = 0;
        var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {
          switch (x) {
            case 6:
              p1 = (0.05 * t1);
              mv1 = t1 - p1;
              x = mv1 / 250000;
              x1 = Convert.ToInt32(x);
              x2 = mv1 - (x1 * 250000);
              if (x2 > 150000) {
                y = x2 - 250000;
                p2 = p1 - y;
                mv2 = (y + x2) + mv1;
              }
              if (x2 < 150000) {
                p2 = p1 + x2;
                mv2 = mv1 - x2;
              }
              k1 = mv2 * 0.02;
              mq1 = mv2 / (d1 - 1);
              s = t1 + k1;
              Label13.Visible = false;
              Label19.Visible = false;

              Label4 = document.getElementById(p2.ToString());
              Label15.Text = mv2.ToString();
              Label6.Text = mq1.ToString();
              Label9.Text = k1.ToString();
              Label10.Text = s1.ToString();
              break;
          }
        }
      }

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Please guide me to achieve my goal.

---

I have applied the solutions suggested below, but my code is still failing. Here is my resulting code after the changes:

```js
function checkValue() {
  var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var j;
  if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {
    j = 5;
    y.options.length = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
      y[i].text = j;
      j++;
    }
  }
  if (t_value > 25000000 & t_value <= 50000000) {
    j = 8;
    y.options.length = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
      y[i].text = j;
      j++;
    }
  }
  if (t_value > 50000000 & t_value <= 100000000) {
    j = 10;
    y.options.length = 6;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {
      y[i].text = j;
      j++;
    }
  }
  if (t_value > 100000000 & t_value <= 200000000) {
    j = 10;
    y.options.length = 11;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
      y[i].text = j;
      j++;
    }
  }
}
function cal() {
  var mv1 = 0, mq1 = 0, k1 = 0, p1 = 0, s = 0, x = 0, x2 = 0, p2 = 0, mv2 = 0, y = 0;
  var x1 = 0;
  var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
  if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {

    switch (x) {
      case 6:
        p1 = (0.05 * t1);
        mv1 = t1 - p1;
        x = mv1 / 250000;
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        x2 = mv1 - (x1 * 250000);
        if (x2 > 150000) {
          y = x2 - 250000;
          p2 = p1 - y;
          mv2 = (y + x2) + mv1;
        }
        if (x2 < 150000) {
          p2 = p1 + x2;
          mv2 = mv1 - x2;
        }
        k1 = mv2 * 0.02;
        mq1 = mv2 / (d1 - 1);
        s = t1 + k1;
        document.getElementById("Label13").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("Label19").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("label15").innerHTML = mv2.toString();
        document.getElementById("label4").innerHTML = p2.toString();
        document.getElementById("label6").innerHTML = mq1.toString();
        document.getElementById("label9").innerHTML = k1.toString();
        document.getElementById("label8").innerHTML = s.toString();
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="checkValue();" /></div>
<input type="button" value="cal" name="button3" onclick="cal();"/>
<label id="Label15"></label>
<label id="Label4"></label>
<label id="Label6"></label>
<label id="Label9"></label>
<label id="Label19"></label>
```

Comment: What are these: Label13, Label19 etc?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing two languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing JavaScript code with ASP.NET code, and that's what's causing the issue. This part is incorrect:

```
Label13.Visible = false;
Label19.Visible = false;

Label4 = document.getElementById(p2.ToString());
Label15.Text = mv2.ToString();
Label6.Text = mq1.ToString();
Label9.Text = k1.ToString();
Label10.Text = s1.ToString();
```

Independently of what the `Label` variables are (they are not defined in the HTML or in the JS) that code will fail (maybe silently, but it will fail). It looks like ASP.NET code, and it will most certainly not work as JavaScript.

Some of the errors above:

- JavaScript does not have a `ToString()` method. It has a `toString()` (notice the lower case t).
- To hide an element in JavaScript you don't do: `element.Visible = false;`. `.Visible` is not JavaScript. You can hide an element by changing its style either by setting the `display` to `none` or the `visibility` to `hidden`:

  ```
  document.getElementById("Label13").style.display = "none";
  ```

  or

  ```
  document.getElementById("Label13").style.visibility = "hidden";
  ```
- To set the text inside an element you don't do `element.Text = "my text";`, you can modify it by changing the `innerHTML`:

  ```
  document.getElementById("Label15").innerHTML = mv2.toString();
  ```

  [notice that the .toString() part isn't really required in JS]

---

**Update after the new code was posted.**

The new code has some issues that make/will make it fail:

- The function `Convert.ToInt32` is from .Net and it does not exist in JavaScript. You could use an "equivalent" in JS: `parseInt` instead.
- JavaScript is case-sensitive, it is important that function and variable names match exactly in uppercase and lowercase (for example: `label15`, `label4`, `label6` should be `Label15`, `Label4`, and `Label6` respectively, and so on with the rest of the variables);
- The variables `d1` and `t1` are undefined and when the code reaches them, it fails and stops. You need to define and assign them (just for testing I assigned them the value `t_value`).
- You are operating with some elements that do not exist in the HTML (`Label13` and `Label8`), when the code reaches them, it will fail and stop. You should comment them or add them. (This may not be a real issue if your code is just a sample of some larger code that actually includes them).

Once that is said, **the code is really specific and it will only work with a *small* combination of values** (the dropdown has to be 7, and the number must be between 5 and 25 million for the code to execute completely).

I have made the specified changes in your code above, and you can see them here:

```js
function checkValue() {
    var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var j;
    if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {
        j = 5;
        y.options.length = 4;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (t_value > 25000000 & t_value <= 50000000) {
        j = 8;
        y.options.length = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (t_value > 50000000 & t_value <= 100000000) {
        j = 10;
        y.options.length = 6;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (t_value > 100000000 & t_value <= 200000000) {
        j = 10;
        y.options.length = 11;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
            y[i].text = j;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
function cal() {
    var mv1 = 0, mq1 = 0, k1 = 0, p1 = 0, s = 0, x = 0, x2 = 0, p2 = 0, mv2 = 0, y = 0;
    var x1 = 0;
    var t_value = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    
    // d1 and t1 were not defined, as a test, I assigned one value
    var t1=t_value;
    var d1=t_value;
    
    if (t_value > 5000000 & t_value <= 25000000) {
        
        switch (x) {
            case 2:
                p1 = (0.05 * t1);
                mv1 = t1 - p1;
                x = mv1 / 250000;
                // replaced Convert.ToInt32 for parseInt
                x1 = parseInt(x);
                x2 = mv1 - (x1 * 250000);
                if (x2 > 150000) {
                    y = x2 - 250000;
                    p2 = p1 - y;
                    mv2 = (y + x2) + mv1;
                }
                if (x2 < 150000) {
                    p2 = p1 + x2;
                    mv2 = mv1 - x2;
                }
                k1 = mv2 * 0.02;
                mq1 = mv2 / (d1 - 1);
                s = t1 + k1;
                // commented the elements that don't exist, and fixed the names for the rest
                //document.getElementById("Label13").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("Label19").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("Label15").innerHTML = mv2.toString();
                document.getElementById("Label4").innerHTML = p2.toString();
                document.getElementById("Label6").innerHTML = mq1.toString();
                document.getElementById("Label9").innerHTML = k1.toString();
                //document.getElementById("Label8").innerHTML = s.toString();
                break;
        }
        
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="checkValue();" /></div>
<input type="button" value="cal" name="button3" onclick="cal();"/>
<label id="Label15"></label>
<label id="Label4"></label>
<label id="Label6"></label>
<label id="Label9"></label>
<label id="Label19"></label>
```

Or on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qvsxtyg4/